# Peek into on-screen terminal session via ssh on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a system running unattended, that most likely try to show some useful error messages on its framebuffer console, as there is an application running in interactive terminal. But there is no screen connected and I only have remote access via ssh.

Is it possible to peek into the on-screen terminal output from within the remote login?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is actually a tool called [peekvc](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/peekvc/) for doing this.

```
# peekvc 1
```

Linux virtual console contents can be accessed through `/dev/vcs#` in plain text and `/dev/vcsa#` with formatting attributes, although neither of those devices provides an easily 'cat'-able format, so you will still need peekvc to decode it.

Note that this *only* applies to virtual consoles. The actual `tty*` devices are pipe-like and do not persist their "contents", nor do they even understand what those contents mean. The separate `vcs*` devices are a feature specific to the Linux built-in "terminal emulator".

---

After peeking at the output, you will probably want to provide some input – the [writevt](https://dataswamp.org/%7Eincal/note_DB/writevt.c) tool will let you do that. This *does* work with any tty type, not limited to virtual consoles.

```
# writevt /dev/tty1 $'whoami\n'
```

(This cannot be done by simply writing to the `tty*` device, as you'd be writing to the wrong end of the pipe – you'd be sending output from a program to the terminal, whereas input is something that programs *read* from the tty device. So you could say the writevt tool "un-reads" the data rather than writes it.)

---

In the future, consider running the application inside a tmux or GNU Screen or Abduco session instead of directly.